# Get file name without extension

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Giving this request:

```
http://myserver.com/images/2341jsdfj.png
```

How can I get apache to redirect it to:

```
http://myserver.com/data/showimage.php?id=2341jsdfj
```

I can only find examples on how to add the extension, not how to remove it..

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/images/([^.]+)\..* http://myserver.com/data/showimage.php?id=$1
```

This expression creates a capturing group for all of the characters before the first . so a.b.png will get mapped to id=a.  But you get the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/images/(.+)(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)?$ http://myserver.com/data/showimage.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This should also accept `my.first.proper.png` and map it to `my.first.proper`. Also the `[L]` postfix asserts no other rules are invoked.